# Visual Studio IDE Javascript format

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I am new to javascript and have been using visual studio to code in it. However, I do not fully understand how to interoperate the helper information that is given to me by the IDE when I type a function with the first open bracket. For example, as shown in the image below, what does createReadStream function actually takes in, outputs, types...etc. How would I read this bit of helper code that is generated by the IDE?

[image: Visual studio helper information]

I have used Xcode and the IDE gives me similar helper information but it is a lot easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options

and then check the way VS shows you the info. You should be able to figure out.

path: string | Buffer -> parameter named path of type string of Buffer

options? : { ... } -> optional parameter named options of type object

and so on...

so the general syntax is parameter_name(?) : parameter_type